# $S(\Bbb{Q}^n)\subseteq \mathcal{P}(\Bbb{Q}^n)$ is Borel and the Borel action of $GL_n(\Bbb{Q})$ on $S(\Bbb{Q}^n)$

Tags: group-actions, topological-groups, descriptive-set-theory, borel-sets

I'm reading this [paper](http://www.ams.org/journals/jams/2003-16-01/S0894-0347-02-00409-5/S0894-0347-02-00409-5.pdf) on torsion-free abelian groups and I'm trying to work out all the details I found at the first page.

Following Fuchs' book on "Infinite Abelian Groups", I was able to explain rigorously to myself why the space of all torsion-free abelian groups of rank $1\le r\le n$, where $n$ is a positive integer, can be identified with the space $S(\Bbb{Q}^n)$ of all non-zero subgroups of $\Bbb{Q}^n$ with $1\le r\le n$ linearly independent elements ($15$-th row of the first page starting after Introduction).

Recall that there is a bijection between the power set $\mathcal{P}(\Bbb{Q}^n)$ and the space $2^{\Bbb{Q}^n}$ of all characteristic functions on $\Bbb{Q}^n$, then we can pull-back on $\mathcal{P}(\Bbb{Q}^n)$ the product topology in such a way that the topology on $\mathcal{P}(\Bbb{Q}^n)$ has the basic open sets of the form $\{A\in\mathcal{P}(\Bbb{Q}^n\mid F_1\subseteq A,F_2\cap A=\emptyset)\}$, where $F_1,F_2$ are finite subsets of $\Bbb{Q}^n$.

(1) Now, in order to prove that $S(\Bbb{Q}^n)$ is a Borel subset of the power set $\mathcal{P}(\Bbb{Q})$ (row $19$), I have used the Lopez-Escobar Theorem.
This result states that, if $L$ is a countable first-order language and $Mod(L)$ is the (Polish) space of countable (hence with universe $\Bbb{N}$) $L$-structures, then invariant Borel subsets of $Mod(L)$ are exactly those of the form $Mod(\sigma)=\{x\in Mod(L)\mid x\models \sigma\}$, for some sentence $\sigma$ in the infinitary logic $L_{\omega_1\omega}$.
**Note:** After the comments of @Ycor, I understand that, probably, I can show directly and in a simpler way that $S(\Bbb{Q}^n)$ is a Borel subset of $\mathcal{P}(\Bbb{Q}^n)$.
So the **$\boldsymbol{1}$-st question** is: how can I prove it?

(2) The author claims that "the natural action of $GL_n(\Bbb{Q})$ on the vector space $\Bbb{Q}^n$ induces a corresponding Borel action on $S(\Bbb{Q}^n)$".
My **$\boldsymbol{2}$-nd question** is: how can I prove the action is Borel?

Using definitions, I tried to prove that the preimage under the function $GL_n(\Bbb{Q})\times S(\Bbb{Q}^n)\to S(\Bbb{Q}^n)$ defined by$((q_{ij})_{i,j},A)\mapsto (q_{ij})_{i,j}\cdot A$ of an open subset of $S(\Bbb{Q}^n)$ is Borel, but I don't get it.
Moreover, I showed that the natural action is actually continuous, but I'm not sure it can help.

(3) Finally (row $25$), the author states that if $A,B\in S(\Bbb{Q}^n)$, then $A\cong B$ iff there exists $\varphi\in GL_n(\Bbb{Q})$ s.t. $\varphi(A)=B$".
As I understand it, I have only to prove that $Aut(\Bbb{Q}^n)=GL_n(\Bbb{Q})$.
Clearly, $\supseteq$ holds.
My **Last question** is: what about $\subseteq$?

I'm a beginner and this is the first paper I read, so try to give an explicit answer, whenever possible.
Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: If I read your second paragraph, I deduce that the "space of torsion-free abelian groups of rank $1$" (which you haven't defined) can be identified to both the space of nonzero subgroups of $\mathbf{Q}$, and of subgroups of rank 1 in $\mathbf{Q}^2$. But there is no natural way to identify these sets.

Comment: For every group $G$, $S(G)$ is a closed subset of $2^G$, this is an immediate fact. It's also immediate that the $\mathrm{Aut}(G)$-action is on $S(G)$ is continuous, just because the action of the symmetric group of $G$ on $2^G$ is continuous.

Comment: @Ycor, I made significant changes in the question and I added the paper in my edit.

Comment: About your first comment, as it is written in the question now, I have used the fact that $\Bbb{Q}\otimes_{\Bbb{Z}}G$ is a divisible hull of the torsion-free abelian group $G$ and that it is isomorphic to $\Bbb{Q}^n$, but it is possible that it is not the right way to do that.

Comment: About your second comment, can you be more explicit, please?

Comment: I'm not sure where to find this but it's well-known and easy to prove.

Comment: @YCor I thought about that for some time, but I was not able to prove it. How can I show that $S(G)$ is closed in $2^G$? I don't see how to use of the axioms of group.  Can you help me, please?

Comment: If $H_n$ is a subgroup and $H_n\to H$ in $G$: clearly $1\in H$, also for any two $g,h\in H$, there exist $n_0$ such that $g,h\in H_n$ for all $n\ge n_0$, hence $gh\in H_n$ for all $n\ge n_0$, and hence $gh\in H$. So $H$ is a subgroup.